# How to run an application installed via pip?

Tags: python, pip

I've used pip before to install libraries to use them in my python scripts. Now I've installed ranger-fm from pip.

Silly question: how do I run it?

I did not expect to run it by simply entering 'ranger' at the command line. I did try

```
python3 -m ranger
```

which gives this error:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: No module named ranger.__main__; 'ranger' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip may have installed a `ranger` or `ranger.py` command. Try to use it directly. Also [read the doc](https://ranger.github.io/documentation.html)

Look perhaps in the directory `~/Library/Python/X.Y/bin` where `X.Y` is your version of Python. Also try

```
python -c 'import site; print(site.getuserbase())'
```

to get the base directory containing the `bin` directory. If ranger is there, add the `bin` directory to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: "Pip may have installed a ranger command." It did not. I already stated that in my question.

Comment: I think this is more of a pip question than a ranger question.

Comment: @user1785730 If it did not install it as the command `ranger`, it may have installed it as `ranger.py`, as suggested by the contents of the  [repository](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/tree/master).

Comment: But that would still tab complete. Anyway, `command not found: ranger.py`

Comment: Look perhaps in the directory `~/Library/Python/X.Y/bin` where X.Y is your version of Python. Also try `python -c 'import site; print(site.getuserbase())'` to get the base directory containing the `bin` directory. If `ranger` is there, add the bin directory to your PATH.